# Calculate difference between grouped elements in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'patient_id': ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p1', 'p2', 'p3'],
              'treatment_time': ['pre', 'pre', 'pre', 'post', 'post', 'post'],
              'val1': [1, 4, 9, 2, 6, 10],
              'val2': [3, 5, 11, 1, 4, 9],
              'val3': [2, 4, 6, 3, 5, 7],
              })
print(df)

  patient_id treatment_time  val1  val2  val3
0         p1            pre     1     3     2
1         p2            pre     4     5     4
2         p3            pre     9    11     6
3         p1           post     2     1     3
4         p2           post     6     4     5
5         p3           post    10     9     7
```

My goal is to group data by `patient_id` and `treatment_time` and to calculate the difference between pre-treatment and post-treatment values. The expected output should look like this:

```
  patient_id  val1  val2  val3
0         p1   1.0  -2.0   1.0
1         p2   2.0  -1.0   1.0
2         p3   1.0  -2.0   1.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with subtract in `MultiIndex DataFrame` selected by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['patient_id','treatment_time'])
print (df1)
                           val1  val2  val3
patient_id treatment_time                  
p1         pre                1     3     2
p2         pre                4     5     4
p3         pre                9    11     6
p1         post               2     1     3
p2         post               6     4     5
p3         post              10     9     7

df = df1.xs('post', level=1).sub(df1.xs('pre', level=1)).reset_index()
print (df)
  patient_id  val1  val2  val3
0         p1     1    -2     1
1         p2     2    -1     1
2         p3     1    -2     1
```

Answer (score 3):

If you always have only one 'pre' and 'post' per patient_id and the rows are sorted to always have pre first and post next, a simple trick would be:

```
cols = df.filter(like='val').columns
out = df.groupby('patient_id')[cols].diff().dropna(how='all')
```

output:

```
>>> out
   val1  val2  val3
3   1.0  -2.0   1.0
4   2.0  -1.0   1.0
5   1.0  -2.0   1.0
```

###### sorting the rows (if needed)

```
df = df.sort_values(by='treatment_time', ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a MultiIndex dataFrame, via `pd.pivot` and subtract `pre` from `post`:

```py
temp = df.pivot('patient_id', 'treatment_time').swaplevel(axis=1)

temp['post'] - temp['pre']

             val1  val2  val3
patient_id                  
p1             1    -2     1
p2             2    -1     1
p3             1    -2     1
```